# How to fix: approved application gets "Client authentication failed" when exchanging authorization code for an access token - on server only

Tags: php, linkedin-api

Locally I am able to authorize my app via LinkedIn but on the server it fails. I have checked that it is the same code running on both.

I am taken to LinkedIn, authorize the app, but then when I try and exchange the code for the token, I get:

{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed"}

I have checked all secrets are the same, etc. and I have made sure that TLS 1.2 and https is being used. I am at a loss to account for any differences.

This is where it fails:

```
$curl = curl_init();

$arr = array();
$arr['grant_type'] = 'authorization_code'; //   The value of this field should always be: authorization_code
$arr['code'] = $_GET['code']; //    The authorization code you received in Step 2.
$arr['redirect_uri'] = SITE_ROOT.'/checkout/linkedin'; //   The same redirect_uri value that you passed in the previous step.   Yes
$arr['client_id'] = LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID; //  The Client ID value generated in Step 1.
$arr['client_secret'] = LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET; //  The Secret Key value generated in Step 1. See the Best Practices Guide for ways to keep your client_secret value secure.

//Get Authorization
curl_setopt_array($curl,  array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE, CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken', CURLOPT_POST => 1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'), CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($arr)));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$resp_decode = json_decode($resp);
$access_token = $resp_decode->access_token;
curl_close($curl);
```

I expect to get an Authorization token but instead (again, only on the server) I get:

{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed"}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: a wild guess: maybe the server cert is not valid or missing....

Comment: Another guess: This probably requires you to specify which domains users can log into your app from, or what URLs are valid redirect URIs, and you neglected to configure this accordingly for your live system …?

Comment: @04FS the redirect is definitely right, this is after it has redirected successfully back.

Comment: @FatFreddy the cert for my site checks out on an SSL checker but would that even come into play if I am making a request from curl?

Comment: well, maybe ... as you handle with ssl and tls... have a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php and the option CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, CURLOPT_SSLCERT CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD and CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE